# string concatenation in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, string-concatenation

I want to achieve this: retrieve a word from a CSV file, then look for the existence of a hashtag with the word in a post the problem is that I was unable to perform the concatenation

[image]

Comment: Please add the actual code in your question instead of an image link. Also take a look at [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Type mismatch" error could be solved by enclosing the concatenation in parentheses, as in:

```
WHERE line[0] =~ (".*#" + line[0] + ".*")
```

However, logically, that `WHERE` clause can never be true. A string cannot be equal to a longer string (itself, preceded by an extra character).

If you just trying to see if a word starts with a hashtag, this should work:

```
WHERE line[0] STARTS WITH "#"
```

Or, if you want to see if there is a hashtag in the string:

```
WHERE line[0] CONTAINS "#"
```

Comment: It wasnt the right image, the code was like :  WHERE p.pst_message =~ ".*#" + line[0] + ".*"

Comment: If so, correct your question. Also, do not use an image. Put the actual text in the question.

Comment: By the way, my basic answer still applies. Enclose the concatenation in parentheses.

Comment: line.csv contains the hashtag that i am searching, whene i have tried WHERE p.post_message =~ (".*#" + line[0] + ".*") the problem does not appear but it returned 0

Comment: No, try this: `WHERE p.pst_message =~ (".*#" + line[0] + ".*")`. As I have said, your original `WHERE` would never work. Also, delete your other question and put the correct info in this question.

Comment: is the same, the question was wrong i have edited it

Comment: If the new `WHERE` still does not work, then it is possible that your CSV file just does not have the data you are looking for. In any case, I have already solved your original problem, which is that you could not perform the concatenation.

Comment: yes thanks, but my file csv conatine one  word (Word) that i have extarcted it from a post (......#Word......), this file is for testing if the code is right; i tried this : p.post_message =~ (".*#" + "Word" + ".*") but is the same thing :(

Comment: Then probably `p.post_message` does not contain the string you think it does. In any case, this is a different question.

Comment: thank you for your help, I hope that I didn't bother you, I am a beginner here ;) but i am sure that p_message contains the hashtag that I am searching for